# looping through array

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm attempting to loop through an array of addresses to check if a certain address (parameter) is in the array.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract RSVP {

    address public Host;
    address[] public rsvpAddresses;

    constructor() {
        Host = msg.sender;
    }

    /// Only the Host can call this function
    error OnlyHost();

    modifier onlyHost() {
        if (msg.sender != Host) {
            revert OnlyHost();
        }
        _;
    }

    function rsvp() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        rsvpAddresses.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function eventStartCheckIn(address payable guest) public onlyHost {
        for (uint i = 0; i < rsvpAddresses.length; i++) {
            if (guest = rsvpAddresses[i])
            guest.transfer(1 ether);
        }
    }

}
```

The error is on line 31 (with the for loop and if statement). "Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable." & "Type address payable is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool."
I feel like these errors occur because the if statement is comparing an address (guest) to an array position but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is because you are using one = instead of double == in the if statement

this should work:

```
if (guest == rsvpAddresses[i])
```